# Disable dropdownlist based on first dropdownlist in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

Can anyone give me an example how to disable dropdown list? What I want is when user choose Coaches and Mentoring or Others, second and third dropdown list will disable. Thank you for your help.

```html
 <tr>
  <td>Action</td>
  <td><select name = "TTID1" id="TTID1" style="width:250px" onchange="otherAction(this.value)">
  <option value="O"></option>
     <option value="600">Classroom Training</option>
    <option value="601">Coaches and Mentoring by IM</option>
    <option value="602">On Job Training</option>
  <option value="9999">Others</option>
  </select></td>
  
  <td>Proposed Training in ILSAS</td>
  <td><select name = "trainGroup1" id="trainGroup1" style="width:250px" onchange="otherIlsas(this.value)">
  <option value="O"></option>
     <option value="700">Power Engineering & Energy Training</option>
    <option value="701">Management Training</option>
    <option value="702">IT & Corporate System Training</option>
  <option value="703">Business Operation Tools Certification</option>
  <option value="9999">Others</option>
  </select></td>
  
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Course</td>
  <td><?php 
  
  $qry="SELECT trainID, trainText FROM tbltraininglist order by traintext asc";
  $result=mysql_query($qry);
  
  echo "<select name = 'trainID1' id='trainID1' style='width:250px' )'>";
  echo "<option value ='null'></option>";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  
    
    ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['trainID'];  ?>"><?php echo $row['trainText']; ?> </option>
   <?php
    } 
  
  ?>
  </select></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#TTID1').change(function() {
         if($(this).val() == "601" || $(this).val() == "9999")
         {
             $('#trainGroup1').prop('disabled', true);
         }
         else
         {
             $('#trainGroup1').prop('disabled', false);
         }
     });
 });
</script>
```

Here is a super basic answer using the onchange event. Making it more dynamic and tweaking it for properly resetting your select fields I'll leave up to you to customise. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example like below :

```js
$('#TTID1').on('change', function(){
    
    if ( $(this).val() == 601 || $(this).val() == 9999 ) {
        
        $('#trainGroup1 option[value="700"], #trainGroup1 option[value="701"]').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#trainGroup1').find('option').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr>
  <td>Action</td>
  <td><select name = "TTID1" id="TTID1" style="width:250px">
  <option value="O"></option>
     <option value="600">Classroom Training</option>
    <option value="601">Coaches and Mentoring by IM</option>
    <option value="602">On Job Training</option>
  <option value="9999">Others</option>
  </select></td>
  
  <td>Proposed Training in ILSAS</td>
  <td><select name = "trainGroup1" id="trainGroup1" style="width:250px">
  <option value="O"></option>
     <option value="700">Power Engineering & Energy Training</option>
    <option value="701">Management Training</option>
    <option value="702">IT & Corporate System Training</option>
  <option value="703">Business Operation Tools Certification</option>
  <option value="9999">Others</option>
  </select></td>
```

Comment: It not work! Am I need to put onchange at Proposed Training in ILSAS dropdown list?

Comment: You should post `otherAction(this.value)`, so i can tweak this function. And one more thing, in your case, to make this things work there is no need to put `onchange` attribute. See my example, i remove the `onchange` function.